# Visualizing timestamps and cummulative time usage python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some sensor data, which essentially is a time stamp, and a status number. A new line, with timestamp and status is recorded semi-periodically (everything from every second to 1 hour). The same status can be repeated over hundreds of lines. I want to represent how long time the component has been in each of the states it can be in.

To get the accumulative time in each sequence I just need to loop over all the records, and sum up all the time spent in each state, right? But how do I visualize this? The idea is to both show how much time is used in each state, acumulated, but also visualize the status and status changes along a date axis.

Suggestions for plot types is welcome.

Example data (unixtime | state): http://pastebin.com/6TmXFZQd

Comment: Interesting question, can you provide some example data to play with?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated with a link to example data. The real records contains thousands upon thousands of rows with large and small gaps.

Comment: Is the format `time|state`? Because the time sometimes decreases `(1404740304|3 --> 1404573443|1)`, is this an error?

Comment: rbierman sorry for the late answer, I have not sorted my example by time (I did sort it by random() as 100 rows would not be that represenative otherwise)

Answer (score 2):

This design is what I would do to visualize the data described in the question:

[image]